# Running mathematica with terminal interface

Tags: batch-file, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to run mathematica with a terminal interface. This is so that I can submit a mathematica program as a batch job to a high performance computing cluster.

Currently I load mathematica using:

```
module load mathematica/9.0.1
```

and then type

```
mathematica
```

to run it. This however opens a GUI interface which I don't think can be submitted as a batch job. Is there anyway to achieve this baring in mind I have no sudo privileges etc

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old but I want to share this for future users:

I have used Mathematica with a terminal interface. You need to write a Wolfram Language Script, which is simply a `.wl` file with Mathematica code in it. Once you have written your file, just execute it in your terminal like this:

Running the script file on Windows:

```
$ "%ProgramFiles%\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\wolfram" -script file.wl
```

Running the script file on Mac:

```
$ /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel -script file.wl
```

Running the script on Linux:

```
$ wolfram -script file.wl
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the text-based interface to Mathematica is here:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingATextBasedInterface.html